# ubuntu backup to NAS fails "not enough space" (Samba)

Tags: server, mount, filesystem, samba

I have a 4tb ubuntu 20.04 samba share on my home server that I want to back up to my ubuntu 20.04 workstation machine to (separate computer entirely). for clarity, the server is running the Ubuntu desktop distro, which is running on a 250gb drive (nearly full) with the 4tb drive mounted to a folder in my home directory on the server. The 4tb drive is empty right now besides a folder (also empty) to hold the backup. the drive is mounted in my home directory and the path to the folder in the drive is shared in smb.conf.

When i try to back up my ubuntu desktop to the server using the provided "Backups" program the back up fails shortly after the program begins scanning my files with an error telling me that there's not enough space in the folder.

Obviously my desktop is seeing the space in the parent drive and not the space in the mounted drive. How can i set up the samba share so that my computer will read the size of the shared 4tb drive and not the drive where its mount folder is?

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you "try to backup"? What command or mouseclick causes the error message? Is your backup running as `root` (UID `0`)? Does `root` get mangled by samba? Read `man hier` and `mount` the 4TB disk outside of your HOME directory.

Comment: Im using the provided "Backups" program that ships with the Ubuntu Distro. No it is not running as root, I'm not getting permission denials. I'll try mounting outside of the home directory. I'm sorry but i dont know what you mean by samba mangling root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, I made 2 changes which solved my problem.

Change 1: Moved the mount point out of my home directory (/home/myusername) and created a folder in /mnt (/mnt/mount_folder) which i used as the mount point for the 4tb drive.

Change 2: I mounted the share via its share name in smb.conf rather than the path. I think that this change is what actually fixed the problem. Mounting with the absolute path when the drive was mounted in my home directory only worked because i had sharing homes enabled in smb.conf.